# Как склеить видео и аудио в один файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть два файла mpeg одной длины (примерно 2 часа). В первом только видео без звука, а во втором только звук без картинки. Как склеить их в один mpeg файл максимально быстро, желательно без использования сторонних приложений (вроде ffmpeg). С помощью программы на python

Comment: С помощью Sony Vegas Pro)

Comment: Какое отношение к вопросу имеют поставленные метки?

Comment: Это нужно сделать с помощью программы на python

Comment: Чем не подходит ffmpeg? Есть обертка для python: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Comment: @insolor спасибо, но крайне желательно чтобы все выполняла одна программа. Я посмотрел библиотеку MoviePy, но не нашел там такого

Comment: @JohnBarrow, http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html `MoviePy depends on the software FFMPEG for video reading and writing.` Т.е. это тоже по сути обертка над FFMPEG.

Comment: Обработка видео - это слишком сложная задача, чтобы выполнять ее только средствами Python. Поэтому берется какая-то готовая библиотека на C/C++ (например, FFMPEG), для нее делается обертка, чтобы можно было работать с ней из Python.